# \ref doesn't seems work

Tags: hyperref, enumerate

Why in this code the correct answer doesn't appear in the Answer Sheet ?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,14pt]{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{exsheets,tikz}

\SetupExSheets[question]{type=exam}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
        \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=ch.qu[1]}
\RenewQuSolPair{question}[headings-format=\large\bfseries,name=Problem]{solution}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{solcount}
\setcounter{solcount}{1}
\newcommand\CC{%
    \ref{ans}\label{sol:\arabic{solcount}}
    \stepcounter{solcount}
}

\newcommand\printmyanswers{%
    \section*{\centering Answers Sheet}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\thequestion}{%
        \noindent
        \x.~\ref{sol:\x}\par
    }
}

\begin{document}

    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    \chapter{Analysis of Algorithms}
    
    \begin{question}
        What is a function?
        
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item First item
                \item Second item\label{ans}
                \item Fourth item
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{question}\printmyanswers

\end{document}
```

In the Answer Sheet, we see "??" in place of number 2.

How can I resolve this problem? Also, I prefer in the Answer Sheet I see like counter of answers be like problem number:
1.1. 2

[image]

Comment: you do not have `\ref{ans}` anywhere, it is in the definition of `\CC`  but you never use that command

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can I change the correct answer in enumerate to CC?

Comment: it's rather hard to guess what you intend this code do do. what did you expect defining `\CC`  to do? If you define a command but don't use it, nothing happens.

Comment: It might be helpful to add a short description of what you're trying to achieve, without worrying about your attempt to implement it.  Like @DavidCarlisle I looked at your code and couldn't really tell what your actual goal was.

Comment: My guess is: instead of `\label{ans}` in the correct choice, you wanted to issue `\CC`; but you also need to change the definition of `\CC` to `\newcommand\CC{\label{sol:\arabic{question}}}`. But I am curious why you are using `exsheet` (which, by the way, is superceded by `xsim`) when you are not using the solution environment it provides. It may be best for you to describe what your needs are and whether you are open to solutions using alternative packages / methods.